# Possible to republish apk under a different name in google play?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

i have published the apk in google play console,
but now i want to delete it and use the exact same code to publish it under the different name,
is it possible to do it? is the code will be lock under google code signing mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same app package and juste change the name of the app, update it in your code AND in your Google Play console, it should do the trick.

If you want to release the app using a different package name, you will need to sign your app with a new certificate, then upload it to Play Console but make sure you removed the first APK (it should appear as a artefact).

You can upload the same code twice, there is no blocking mechanism at the moment.